# identity matrix shape of ridge regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, python, ridge-regression

I am trying to apply manually ridge regression for the b coefficients. So i am trying to make the inverse matrix from this formula: $\left( X^T X + \lambda I \right)^{-1}$, but I am not sure which should be the shape of my identity matrix $I$.

So on Python I do this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(100, size = 30).reshape(10, 3) 
y = np.random.randint(100, size = 10).reshape(10, 1)
x = sm.add_constant(x)
matrix_inverse = np.linalg.inv(x.T @ x + np.identity(x.shape[1]) * alpha)
```

Is the formula above correct? My only doubt is about the shape of the identity matrix. Is it the `x.shape[1]`?

Comment: Matrix addition in ridge regression works the same way as in other contexts. Is there a particular concept in matrix addition that you're having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is a $10 \times 3$ matrix, $X^T$ is a $3 \times 10$ matrix, so $X^T X$ will be a $3 \times 3$ matrix. You can add matrices with the same shape, so $\lambda I$ must be a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and because multiplying a matrix with a constant does not change it's shape, you must use a $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.

In short: yes, you should use `x.shape[1]`.